# Rolling 7 Day Periods in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I’m trying to figure out how to create rolling 7 day periods. I have horizontal bar charts that are currently grouped by week, but I actually want them to be grouped by 7 day periods instead.

I used the Superstore data as an example. The top row in this image should be the last 7 days, with the latest date being in the top right, and so forth. Is this possible?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a field to use as a dimension for this assuming you choose some anchor date to specify the beginning of a 7-day period. For this example, I’ll choose a literal date of July 4, 1776 but you could use the Today() function or the min or max transaction date in your data or whatever you like.

Then the DIV() and DATEDIFF() functions are all you need to calculate the number of 7 day periods Between the anchor date and the period containing [Order Date].

```
DIV(DATEDIFF('day', #7/4/1776#, [Order Date]), 7)
```

You’ll typically want to treat this field as a discrete dimension.

In the example below, I called the field [Period] and also displayed the earliest and latest dates found in the data for each Period.

[image]

In a more production oriented example, you may want to hide the header for the Period field and instead calculate the start/end dates for periods rather than draw them from the data, so that they show correctly if there were period boundaries without any transactions.

The formula to compute the [Period Start] is `DATE(DATEADD('day', [Period] * 7, #7/4/1776#))` and to compute [Period End] is `DATE(DATEADD('day', [Period] * 7 + 6, #7/4/1776#))` If you are going to use the anchor date in many formulas, it would be convenient to define it in one place with a parameter or calculated field.

Comment: Thank you. This kind of worked. What it gave me was one row at the bottom with the last 7 days in it, but the bars above that were just individual days. I have a date range selected and was hoping to see multiple groups of 7 days. Can this be done?

Comment: I wonder if I can accomplish this using an If then statement. If within last 7 days of chosen date “w1”, else if between 15 and 8 “w2”. But I’m not sure how to write this in Tableau

Comment: See the revised answer. This example doesn't have anything on Detail or other shelves on the marks card. If you still have trouble, publish a workbook - say to Tableau Public - to allow diagnosis.

Comment: See the link to Tableau Public here: https://public.tableau.com/views/SuperstoreTest_15898411605390/Sheet1?:display_count=y&:origin=viz_share_link

Comment: Sheet2 shows what I’m working on. See how the bottom row has all of the colored Date parts? Every row should be like that. And with 7 days in reach bar.

Comment: You are treating Period as a Measure. Change it to a dimension. You can change the default behavior on the data pane on the left sidebar, but that won't change the role on any existing viz. So also click on the Period pill on the the Row shelf and change it to a Dimension in that case as well. When you do that, Tableau will make it Continuous (green). You'll want to change it back to discrete (blue) and probably pull it the left to make it the first field on the Row shelf. You can also hide header for the field, again click on it to get the menu, or move it to Detail

Comment: The easy way to tell at a glance whether a field is being treated as a Dimension or Measure is to look for an aggregation function on the pill. If you see SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, AGG or the like it is a measure. If you don't see an aggregation function, it is being treated as a dimension. A field's data aggregation role can be different on different views, the role in the data source is simply a default.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I really appreciate it. I would have never thought to change Period to a dimension.

Comment: You're welcome. I mentioned that in the answer, but it's easy to overlook. If you don't mind, consider upvoting the answer. Good luck, enjoy Tableau, and learn about the difference between dimensions and measures. That's key to being successful with Tableau.